# Is it unlawful to create an origin-specific organization?

Tags: discrimination, citizenship, nationality

Suppose I establish a high school, college, or university where anyone can enroll, but I stipulate that

1. The teachers, researchers, or top-level administration must be born in, say, Japan, Egypt, or Malaysia.
2. Also, the person must have a bachelor's degree from those countries.
3. Any student born in, say, Oman or Zimbabwe, can enjoy a tuition fee waiver.
4. These stipulations won't be applied to the native citizens.

Will that be lawful in:

1. the USA
2. the UK
3. France

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), this kind of discrimination is generally legal, but it is very uncommon because under the Civil Rights Act of 1964, it would disqualifiy the school from receiving any federal funding.

Note, though, that what you're describing is discrimination on the basis of national origin, not on the basis of race, which is what your headline asked about.

If you were to open a school and limit it to white students or to black students, this would be unlawful under 42 USC 1981.

Answer (score 1):

### Not without an [exemption](https://antidiscrimination.nsw.gov.au/anti-discrimination-nsw/organisations-and-community-groups/exemptions-and-certifications.html/)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Under both Commonwealth and state law, discrimination on the basis of national origin is unlawful. However, exemptions can be applied for, and are granted.